# How to add a profile picture in AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I want to add a profile picture to the emails I send through Amazon Simple Email Service (SES), I know it has been known to be not supported, but I could not ignore the fact that Amazon [dot] com/in emails contain a profile picture, I'm assuming here that amazon [dot] com/in use AWS SES themselves.

Help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

**BIMI** (Brand Indicators for Message Identification) allows you to display a sender logo alongside your messages in the email inbox, when verified under a set of [BIMI specifications](https://bimigroup.org/implementation-guide/).

Link to inspect a domain's BIMI config https://bimigroup.org/bimi-generator/

Answer (score 1):

**The AWS SES API doesn't support this.**

And just because you see the avatar in an email coming from `amazon.in` **doesn't mean** they use SES themselves.

However, when receiving emails, the `SES API` client itself will get the avatar image automatically based on the given email, provided that email service supports avatar images.

Comment: "the SES API client itself will get the avatar image automatically based on the given email", could you please elaborate on this part? how do i do it ?

Comment: Do what? There's nothing you can do to have an avatar image with SES for outbound emails.

Comment: any guesses on how AWS does it?

Comment: amazon.in uses SES. We can verify it by looking at original message, it contains message ID <random-characters@eu-west-1.amazonses.com>

Answer (score 1):

I found this alternative to BIMI - maybe it will be useful to others as well.

The caveat is that it will only display your logo to Gmail users, but it is free and much easier to set up than BIMI. It met my needs.

> SOLUTION:
> Simply go to google.com, sign-out of your account. Create a NEW google account, and make sure to select the option to create it using your existing email address. Then use the yourname@yourdomain.com email address. This will create a Google account for your yourname@yourdomain.com. Now that you are sign in, go to google.com and click on the upper right hand corner Icon, it will let you change your profile of your Google account (which is now your Google Plus account linked to yourname@yourdomain.com). In the Google Plus account, simply update your profile photo and save it. It takes a few hours to update, and then BOOM, you’re done! That profile photo will show up as your email profile photo when you send emails as yourname@yourdomain.com!

Once you've gone through these steps, it will show your logo on all emails sent from the address you set up, regardless of where it's sent from (AWS SES, 3rd party email, etc).

Here's the blog post where I found this approach:
https://utechpia.com/how-to-add-an-email-profile-picture-to-any-domain-email-address/